# Sort Desktop icons by reverse of "Date Created"?

Tags: macos, icon, desktop, sort

I want my oldest folders to be at the top and my newest ones to be at the bottom. Sorting my Desktop by "Date Created" does the opposite of this, but how do I flip it?

I'm on macOS Sierra and have been hunting around for a while without finding anything. Having no option for this would be ridiculously stupid on a "modern" operating system.

Comment: I don't understand your question because when I click on 'Date Created' I can change the sort from most recent to oldest with each click (the arrow on the header indicates the sort).

Comment: @fsb I don't see this option. I right-click on my desktop, go to Sort By -> Date Created. This places a check mark nex to "Date Created", and clicking on it again does not reverse the order.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, I thought you were referring to the Desktop in Finder.   You mean the actual Desktop.

Comment: It is hard to believe, but this is still an issue!